# Should .rvmrc files be used in ruby gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently looking at upgrading a gem to Rails 3, some work has already put in and the gem now supports Rails 3 with Ruby 1.9.2. The fork also includes an .rvmrc file which specifies ruby 1.9.2. Should gems use .rvmrc files to specify a ruby version when they can be compatible with multiple versions of ruby? When I try to install the gem on ree from ruby gems the gem complains that I need ruby 1.9.2. Is this because of the .rvmrc file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add .rvmrc to your gem.

I forgot one and my users started complaining: the whole stuff didn't work because of ruby versions incompatibilities...

A workaround would be to load your gem content only if the current Ruby version is ok.

You'd prepend your main class with a:

```
 if RUBY_VERSION >= 1.9
```